# upload employee image into SQL database along with other info with insert query

Tags: c#, image, insert

I am having problem with uploading my employee photo to database with c#. I have an employee entry screen form. On that form there is various info about employee like (name, address,salary,joining date, birth date, image, mobile no etc).

my insert query is working very well without the image. here is my code sample.

```
 query = "insert into tbl_emp values('" + txtempid.Text + "','" + txtempname.Text + "','"+ cmbSex.Text +"','"
                + cmbDepartment.Text +"','" + cmbEmpDesig.Text + "','" + cmbemptyp.Text + "','" 
                + txtsalary.Text + "','"+ txtParmanentAdd.Text +"','"+ txtPresentAdd.Text +"','"
                + txtContactNo.Text +"','"+ txtEmailAdd.Text +"','"+ dateBirth.Text +"','" 
                + dateJoin.Text + "','"+ txtCardNo.Text +"')";
           con.executeCmd_Sql(query);
```

Please suggest me how to insert image along with these other info. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you have some serious sql injection going on there. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Look at this question and its answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729854/asp-net-adding-images-to-sql-table-what-am-i-doing-wrong?rq=1

Comment: you meant to say that, I need to use variable instead of using textbox values directly? Thats what I understand after reading the link. Any way Thanks. I'll definitely avoid this SQL injection next time.

Answer (score 1):

(assuming you are using ASP.NET webforms)
.aspx:

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" ID="img" ImageUrl="~/Chrysanthemum.jpg" />
```

codebehind (.cs):

```
 string pic = img.ImageUrl;
```

It is not really a best practice to save actual pictures (like binary data) into a database. That's why you would usually just take the path to the picture (like `"~/mypicture.jpg"`) and save that as a string in your database. So basically, all you have to do is pass in the string `pic` in your query.

Unrelated: but your query is very open to SQL injection. i would advise you to read this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

Inserting images are easy. You just need to convert the image into a byte array. Look at this code fragment sample:

```
private void updatedata()
{

    //use filestream object to read the image.

    //read to the full length of image to a byte array.

    //add this byte as an oracle parameter and insert it into database.

    try
    {

        //proceed only when the image has a valid path

        if (imagename != "")
        {

            FileStream fs;

            fs = new FileStream(@imagename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            //a byte array to read the image

            byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];

            fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

            fs.Close();

            //open the database using odp.net and insert the data

            string connstr = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestImage;
            Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);

            conn.Open();

            string query;

            query = "insert into test_table(id_image,pic) values(" + 
            textBox1.Text + "," + " @pic)";

            SqlParameter picparameter = new SqlParameter();

            picparameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;

            picparameter.ParameterName = "pic";

            picparameter.Value = picbyte;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(picparameter);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Image Added");

            cmd.Dispose();

            conn.Close();

            conn.Dispose();

            Connection();

        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

    }

}
```

If you need more information, look at [this website](http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/) which explains everything you need to know. This code fragment I pasted here from that site.